# wget redownloading a file only if it has been update on the server

Tags: wget

I am currently using wget to downloads assets from a server. I currently use the following options of `wget`

```
wget --user=m_username --password=m_password  -r -np -x -nH -q -nc URL_PATH

 /**
     *  -r   - download recursively
     *  -np  - no parent ( only the files below a certain hierarchy will be downloaded)
     *  -x   - force to create the same directory structure.
     *  -nH  - Disable generation of host-prefixed directories
     *  -q   - quiet - no output.
     *  -nc  - existing files will not be redownloaded.
     *
     * */
```

In addition to the above options I want wget to re-download the file if the file has been updated in the server. Is there an option that I can use for that. I couldn't find anything specifically for that.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `-N`: "When running Wget with -N, with or without -r or -p, the decision as to whether or not to download a newer copy of a file depends on the local and remote timestamp and size of the file."

Comment: I can't use `-N` option with `-nc` option.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the manual pages:

> --no-clobber
>
> If a file is downloaded more than once in the same directory, Wget's behavior depends on a few options, including -nc.  In certain
>   cases, the local file
>       will be clobbered, or overwritten, upon repeated download.  In other cases it will be preserved.
>
> When running Wget without -N, -nc, -r, or -p, downloading the same file in the same directory will result in the original copy of file
>   being preserved and
>       the second copy being named file.1.  If that file is downloaded yet again, the third copy will be named file.2, and so on.  (This is
>   also the behavior
>       with -nd, even if -r or -p are in effect.)  When -nc is specified, this behavior is suppressed, and Wget will refuse to download newer
>   copies of file.
>       Therefore, ""no-clobber"" is actually a misnomer in this mode---it's not clobbering that's prevented (as the numeric suffixes
>   were already preventing
>       clobbering), but rather the multiple version saving that's prevented.
>
> When running Wget with -r or -p, but without -N, -nd, or -nc, re-downloading a file will result in the new copy simply overwriting
>   the old.  Adding -nc
>       will prevent this behavior, instead causing the original version to be preserved and any newer copies on the server to be ignored.
>
> When running Wget with -N, with or without -r or -p, the decision as to whether or not to download a newer copy of a file depends on the
>   local and remote
>       timestamp and size of the file.  -nc may not be specified at the same time as -N.
>
> A combination with -O/--output-document is only accepted if the given output file does not exist.
>
> Note that when -nc is specified, files with the suffixes .html or .htm will be loaded from the local disk and parsed as if they had been
>   retrieved from
>       the Web.

From my understanding what you really want is just the `--mirror` option, which sets the `-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing` flags.